# What does the "Chat User" checkbox on the User object do?

Tags: liveagent, user-management, chat

It's a simple question which I couldn't find an answer to: `What does the "Chat User" checkbox on the User object do?`.

What I found:

- [User Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm). There is a field - `UserPermissionsLiveAgentUser`:

> Indicates whether the user is enabled to use Chat (true) or not (false). Label is Live Agent User.

- `Chat User` field is salesforce internal field and this is not exposed or access to API which can be queried or retrieved. [Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000XxAOQA0)
- In [Create Chat Users](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.live_agent_create_users.htm&type=5) help documentation it is mentioned:

> Select Chat User. If you don’t see this checkbox, verify that your support organization has purchased enough Chat feature licenses.

The help article I mentioned above is for Set Up Chat **in Salesforce Classic**. So I am wondering if we still need this checkbox in Lightning and what it is needed for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chat user field (UserPermissionsLiveAgentUser) is needed if the user has to work on Salesforce chat. This checkbox assigns the Chat licence/Permission to the user to be able to access the Omni Chat functionalities. This is needed in lightning as well to give the chat access.

Note : To use omni-channel chat, we also need the Service cloud user checkbox selected