# Can I test live support via Embedded Chat without Chat User license?

Tags: developer-console, debugging, licenses, chat

The company I started to work for has asked me to fix the Embedded Chat, but I have no experience with Salesforce and can't find an answer to my question so far.

The company has Service Cloud licenses available, but no Chat User license available (there is only one but it's in use and I can't find the user assigned to it).

I want to debug/test the live support, I mean to turn "Chat with an Expert" on the chat button on the company website visitors just to test the live chat feature.

Is there a way to achieve this wihtout a Chat User license? Maybe via some development or debug mode? Or perhaps through some setup that doesn't require Chat User license at all? Or I might leaning a way to search who is using the Chat User license to land me for a while?

Comment: can you create a sandbox from your PROD org and reassign the license to you? Can you login as that user in PROD and test from there?

Comment: @cropredy yes, but I don't know which user is assigned to the Chat User license in order to reassign the license to me and later back to that user after the tests. Do you know how to find who is assigned to the Chat User license?

Comment: [this should help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/379493/2602) - it is a specific User permission that can be queried